# post variable not passed to php

Tags: php, html, ajax, http, post

I am trying to send a POST variable through an AJAX call and it seems the php script isn't receiving it. Here is my html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test">Testing</h1>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search"/>
    <div id="target">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_call(){
    var hr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var target=document.getElementById("target");
    hr.open("POST", "phptest.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type"," application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
            var data=(hr.responseText);
            target.innerHTML="";
            target.innerHTML+=data;

        }
    }
    hr.send("test="+document.getElementById("test").innerHTML);
}
ajax_call();
</script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/friends2.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP file :-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
//$search=$_POST['search'];
/*if(empty($_POST)){
    echo "not set";
}*/

echo $_POST['test'];
?>
```

I removed the JSON parse and  when i uncomment that if(empty..) line i see "not set"

Comment: You have not placed the `search` input in the `XHR` request.

Comment: i was trying to pass the h1 element, not the search element, and trying to print it back in the div

Comment: Have you changed the Content-Type as in my example, have you looked at the console log

Comment: Yes, I have. I removed the Json parse and now i'm getting an error "undefined index: test....." and there is "null" in the next line

Comment: If you get any errors in console log, let us know what they are so we can help you further.

Comment: Wow it's working!
 I've been battling with this for hours. Could it be that this entire mess was caused by the setRequestHeader mistake I initially had? Because I don't see any other differences. 
Thank you for help, Danny. Now maybe I can finally move on.

Comment: It was the Content-Type, plus the fact you were bringing back a non JSON string and trying to parse it within the xhr request. So there was two things really. But if you checked your console log you should have got an error about Content-Type expecting 2 parameters, this would have solved your first one, second one you have seen in the network of your browser by clicking the file and seeing the data going through fine but not coming back correctly, after fixing the content-type one of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify content-type to the correct format

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test">Testing</h1>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search"/>
    <div id="target">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_call(){
    var params = "test="+document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    console.log(params);
    var hr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var target=document.getElementById("target");
    hr.open("POST", "phptest.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
            var data=hr.responseText;
            target.innerHTML="";
            target.innerHTML+=data;

        }
    }
    hr.send(params);
}
ajax_call();
</script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/friends2.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

You may want to remove the JSON.parse() so you can see any debugging you may be doing on your PHP side, otherwise you need to change your PHP to bring back a JSON string.

Check your browser's developer console to check the output of your PHP script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I tried adding those lines you suggested but when I navigate directly to the php file, I can still see "not set" when I uncomment that if(empty..) line of code. It means that the php file just isn't getting that POST variable, doesnt it?

Comment: If you directly go to the PHP file you will always see "not set" as your not posting data yourself the XHR sends the request, check the console log in your browser look for the file it is submitting data too and see what it shows then.

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there are few issues

1. On the setRequestHeader (which takes 2 arguement, but were only given one in your sample code)

   hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
2. Your php code needs to return a json format e.g

   echo '{"message":"'.$_POST['test'].'"}';
3. Your page needs to get the value from the parsed json (note the 'message' as per the php code)

   target.innerHTML+=data.message;

Comment: Why does it need to return json? Can send text or HTML or XML or whatever

Comment: Ah it does not have to, just used json because I saw that your php file is returning a application/json header. :)